# Wifi turns off when phone sleeps - Not Duplicate

Tags: wi-fi, 5.1-lollipop, standby, sleep

This is NOT a duplicate, I have read the other posts on this forum site and none of them have helped me. I've gone to the wifi settings and made sure Keep Wi-Fi on during sleep is ALWAYS and I've tried the WifiFixer, that didn't work. So I have no idea what to do. I don't have any of those crummy battery saving apps either.

If this helps, I tried switching to the guest profile once, and it was solved (but I obviously don't want to use the Guest profile all the time. So maybe it's linked with my Google Account?

I'm on a Motorola Moto G (1st Gen) and I'm on Android 5.1